# Не могу запустить веб сервер после обновления из за Hangfire

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, hangfire

Всем привет. После нового обновления я не могу запустить веб. приложение в обычном IIS.
Вот ошибка которую я получаю:

```
HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure
```

Лог:

```
Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Hangfire.Core, Version=1.7.23.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Не удается найти указанный файл.

File name: 'Hangfire.Core, Version=1.7.23.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

   at SMSServicePanel.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)

   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)

   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.InvokeCore(Object instance, IServiceCollection services)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<Invoke>g__Startup|0(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IServiceCollection services)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<Build>b__0(IServiceCollection services)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.UseStartup(Type startupType, HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<UseStartup>b__0(HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()

   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()

   at SMSServicePanel.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Исходники проекта SMSServicePanel\SMSServicePanel\Program.cs:line 21
```

В IIS Expres на VS всё отлично работает, на сервере не хочет. В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я очень долго искал ответ, вот решение.
При установке пакетов Hangfire в файл project.csproj была вписана неправильная версия. В моём случае 1.7.23. При запуске веб приложения требовалась же версия 1.7.23.0. Решением стало изменение версии в файле project.csproj с 1.7.23 на 1.7.23.0.